# How to block apps in the new Facebook interface?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Since one Facebook update some time ago, the procedure at the following FAQ page

- [How do I block or unblock an app?](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=121070141307903)

Doesn't work anymore. How to block an app now?

List of Applications that seem as though they cannot be blocked

- https://apps.facebook.com/flixster/
- https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=25605183774767

Comment: That works for me. Is it showing any error or something?

Comment: The help page in your link totally worked for me.

Comment: @phwd: This seems like another total mess from Facebook. In order to block the app you mention in the bounty text you have to allow access (which then gives you access to the fan page) and then you can go through and block the app. Very strange indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook apps [no longer have profile pages](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/), although the developer has the option of creating a page linked to the app.  Since that is the page containing the option to block the app and it is now optional, there may not be a way to block the app from the Facebook interface any more for these apps.  That does seem like an issue for Facebook to address.  However, in the mean time it can still be done from a script.  A search found [this userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/123403) which adds a Block link to the bottom of the authorization dialog (before Report App), allowing you to block the app from there.  I tried it on the BWS app and successfully blocked it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Account Settings.
2. Choose the Apps tab.

Comment: There is no longer any way to block or unblock an app from the Apps tab.

Answer (score 2):

I have a [Facebook note describing how to do this](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150711015139900). I'll repeat it here:

Go to [Privacy settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy) and select "Manage blocking" at the bottom of the page (under Blocked People and Apps).

[image: Privacy settings]

On the next page, under "Block apps" you'll see a text-box where you can type in the names of apps to search for and block.

[image: Block apps setting]

Note: this does not work on the mobile version of Facebook (website, not the app), as the block applications option never appears, and you can't get to the desktop site version of the privacy settings... :-(

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to facebook account
2. Go to your account settings
3. Go to Apps and websites
4. You will see the list of all the apps that you approved.
5. Click on the app that you hate and then click on Remove application.

Comment: This only *removes* the application. It does not block it.