# Block requests from apps in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Some Facebook friends are playing games on Facebook such as Empires & Allies and Hidden Chronicals. I never tried those games or gave them permission to contact me, but I receive annoying daily requests to join.

I've tried to find our how block this request messages, and some web pages point me to: http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

But neither Empires & Allies or Hidden Chronicals are on this page, and reporting this apps as spam does not solve it either.

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-to-block-apps-in-the-new-facebook-interface

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I block app and game invitations once for all in Facebook?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25310/how-can-i-block-app-and-game-invitations-once-for-all-in-facebook)

Answer (score 3):

From the Facebook News Feed click on **Apps and Games** in the left sidebar, or go to https://www.facebook.com/games.  Any requests from friends should appear at the top.  Go the upper right corner of the request and click the X that appears.  That will hide that request and provide the option of blocking the application, or ignoring all requests from that person.

If you are not receiving requests/invites but it is just appearing your News Feed, and you do not want to see those, you can hide all game stories from particular people, or all stories from a particular game.  Just hover over one of those posts in your News Feed, click on the ∨ that appears in the upper right corner of the post, and choose the desired option.

Comment: Hard to tell which answer would be correct. This one worked as well. Voted up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Visit this link and block all the apps: http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy&section=apps&h=AQPcSIPevfWeeqXJ

From now on, if you receive any request from them, click on the small arror that appears above it and select, "Hide/Ignore all Requests for ***_*__**"

Also go to the "Blocked People and Apps" page to block the particular Apps and App Requests from the particular friends of your who send you those requests.

Comment: As I told in my last paragraph, neither Empires & Allies or Hidden Chronicals are on the list, so... how do I block them?

Comment: @Osvaldo i have edited my answer to account for that.

Comment: I think I've found it. It's in the "Blocked People and Apps
" section, and I was looking in the "Apps games and websites" section. PFF I'll wait to see if it's effective and post the result here.